# "I hope" vs "I want"

Tags: usage, expressions

One says from bottom of his heart,

> I don't want him to be humiliated because of me.
>   I hope that he will not be humiliated because of me.

Until this day, I thought "I don't want" makes more sense, because it shows a more stronger will.

But I then I was told it sounds more native to say "I hope"...
Now I'm confused...

Comment: [correction: until today, not this day]

Answer (score 1):

I would use either as a native speaker and both are acceptable.

*I hope* describes it more as a desirable action rather than as a necessity.

It’s kind of like you hope he won’t be humiliated but you are not taking any action to prevent it.

*I don’t want* implies you are actively taking steps to prevent and stop the humiliation and it has more meaning to you than if you say *I hope*.

Comment: +1 for noting that hoping implies you don't intend to take action for this, like just crossing your fingers. I don't want shows that you are actively opposed and might take action

Answer (score 0):

"I hope" implies that whatever follows is desirable.

"I don't want" simply implies that whatever follows is not desired, but that does not necessarily mean that the opposite is desired.

For example,

> I don't want him to be humiliated because of me, but I am obligated to report the incident.

Here the speaker is emphasizing that the other person's humiliation is not their goal but may be a consequence of their actions nonetheless.